# Swift dismissing view with clunky animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, dismiss

I simply have a `ViewController` that I would like to `dismiss`. And this is my `dismissAction`:

```
@objc private func dismissView(){
    
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    UserDefaultsService.shared.updateDataSourceArrayWithWishlist(wishlist: self.wishList)
    let dataSourceArray = UserDefaultsService.shared.getDataSourceArray()
    //  update datasource array in MainVC
    self.dismissWishlistDelegate?.dismissWishlistVC(dataArray: dataSourceArray, dropDownArray: self.dropOptions, shouldDeleteWithAnimation: false, wishlistToDelete: self.wishList)

}
```

**Proble:**

The dismiss  animation is very `clunky` and not fluent at all. I found out that if I remove everything in the function but only call `self.dismiss` it is working perfectly fine. What is the issue here? Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: `dismissWishlistVC` is probably a big function with lots of loops or stuff. Try putting everything in there in a background thread if you can.

Comment: @aheze I think the issue is `UserDefaultsService.shared.updateDataSourceArrayWithWishlist(wishlist: self.wishList)`. Because if I remove that line it works smoothly.

Comment: Possibly. What does that function do?

Comment: @aheze pretty much exactly what is says :D `dataSourceArray` is `[Wishlist]`  so it is looking for the the given `Wishlist` and then replaces the old one with the given one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to light-weight load in main thread by

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
   UserDefaultsService.shared.updateDataSourceArrayWithWishlist(wishlist: self.wishList)
}
```

And instead of `let dataSourceArray = UserDefaultsService.shared.getDataSourceArray()` use `self.wishList` directly in the last line

Comment: thanks, what was wrong with my question... I love and hate SO